# Skrollr JS on scroll issue of div overlapping in Mozilla browser 50.00 version in windows 10

Tags: jquery, css, mozilla, skrollr

I have an issue in Mozilla browser with Skrollr JS. Please check below link.

```
<b>https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBjRGK</b>
```

When you will scroll down in the link provided, In Mozilla browser you face the issue of div border radius corner are visible. This issue is only in Mozilla browser and not in chrome.

Please also check attache image
[image]

Please check and suggest if any fix around is there or not. Help will be appreciated.

Thaks in advance.

Comment: it was not reproduced in FireFox MacBook pro.Could you please tell in detail

Comment: This issue is in Firefox 50.00 version in windows 10

Comment: That looks like an old version of FF. I checked in FF 61.0 - Window 10 and it looks fine